Malta visit visa with no travel history for Pakistani passport
I have no travel history. But I have a strong profile. I am a government officer. One of my friend is self employed in malta. He runs a business over there. He has offered me a visit to malta. Since it is a Schengen state. And i have heard that it's not easy to get a Schengen state visa without any travel history. He is ready to send me a sponsor letter. Please guide me will it work or how to proceed in the visa requirements so that i can get a visa. I am a Pakistani passport holder.

Start with background reading such as Malta visa for Indians

Does this answer your question? Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing? Also see here for related questions
